# In Python is there a way using yfinance library to download 10y history of Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Cash flow?

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance, yfinance

Using **Python** and the **yfinance** library, is there a way to download a long period of quarterly or yearly financial statements (I'd prefer quarterly) **like 10 years**?

I am interested in Balance Sheet, Income statement, and cash flow. The common script from yfinance library allows you to download 4y of history or 4quarters of history, I would be more interested in 6y of quarterly history.

I tried to put a code like this, but it does not work.

```py
gs = yf.Ticker('gs')

gs.balancesheet(period='5y')
```

Many many thanks in advance for your help,

Regards

Comment: It's impossible, YF only provides data for 4y financials. You have to scrape data elsewhere by yourself (roic.ai, has it, but not full financials, basic + ratios, also check https://fmpcloud.io/ since Ur using Python)